# Is the following conditional statement: $\,(p\land q) \to p\,$ a tautology?

Tags: propositional-calculus

> Is $(p\land q) \to p$ a tautology?

**So far I did the following**

$$(p\land q)\to p \equiv \lnot (p\land q)\lor p \equiv (\lnot p\lor ¬q)\lor p$$

I'm having trouble trying to show that the conditional statement above is a tautology without using a truth table.

I'm assuming you would have to use logical equivalence to figure the rest  of this out.

I know that a tautology is true, regardless of the truth-value assignments of the variables. Can someone help me finish this? Any additional explanation is welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, your initial work is correct:

$$(p\land q)\to p \equiv \lnot (p\land q)\lor p\tag{implication}$$

$$\equiv (\lnot p \lor \lnot q) \lor p\tag{DeMorgan's rule}$$

---

Now using the properties of associativity and commutativity of the $\lor$-operator, we have:

$$\equiv \lnot p \lor \lnot q \lor p\tag{associativity}$$

$$\equiv \lnot p \lor p \lor \lnot q \tag{commutativity}$$

$$\equiv (\lnot p \lor p)\lor \lnot q \tag{associativity}$$

$$\equiv \underbrace{(\lnot p \lor p)}_{\large \top} \lor \lnot q$$

$$\equiv \top \lor \lnot q\tag{Law of the excluded middle}$$
$$ \equiv \top \tag{annihilator of $\lor$}$$

Note that $\top$ is represents *tautologically true.*

This is true regardless of the truth value assigned to p or to q.

Comment: Aaah I see, thank you very much.

Comment: You're welcome, J.Z.!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a method called the 'short truth-table' method.  As the name implies, it is not a full truth-table.

The idea is that you try to make the statement false ... and if you find that you cannot do that, then that means that the statement *must* be true, i.e. it is a tautology.

OK, so let's see what it would take for $(p \land q) \rightarrow p$ to be False.  Well, a conditional can only be false when the antecedent is true, and the consequent is false. So, in order for $(p \land q) \rightarrow p$ to be false, we need that $p \land q$ is True, and that $p$ is False.  OK, but for $p \land q$ to be True, both $p$ and $q$ need to be True.  But that means we have a problem, because now we have that $p$ must both be True and False. So ... we conclude that it is impossible for $(p \land q) \rightarrow p$ to be False ... meaning it is a tautology.

Here is that same method, but simply with annotating the statements (the indices show the order in which I place the truth-values, and the red shows the contradiction):

\begin{array}{ccccccc}
( & p & \land & q & ) & \rightarrow & p\\
\hline
& \color{red}T_4 & T_2 & T_5 && F_1 & \color{red}F_3\\
\end{array}

Another thing you can do is a formal proof: if you can derive $(p \land q) \rightarrow p$ from no premises at all, then that means the statements is a tautology. Here is a proof using a proof system called Fitch (there are many different proof systems):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

We will massage 
$$(p\wedge q) \rightarrow p$$ into $\mbox{TRUE}$ 
showing justifications for each step.

By definition of the "implies" relation, 
$$(p\wedge q) \rightarrow p = \lnot (p\wedge q) \lor q$$

By negation of an and relationship
$$(p\wedge q) \rightarrow p = \lnot (p\wedge q) \lor p = ( (\lnot p) \lor (\lnot q) \lor p $$ 
By associativity and commutativity of the or relationship

$$(p\wedge q) \rightarrow p =(\lnot p) \lor ((\lnot q) \lor p )
= (\lnot p) \lor (p \lor (\lnot q) ) =  ((\lnot p) \lor p) \lor (\lnot q) $$

By the "law of the excluded middle" 
$$(p\wedge q) \rightarrow p = ((\lnot p) \lor p) \lor (\lnot q) = (\mbox{TRUE}) \lor q$$

By the axiom that $\forall s: \mbox{TRUE} \lor s = \mbox{TRUE} $
$$(p\wedge q) \rightarrow p = (\mbox{TRUE}) \lor q = \mbox{TRUE}$$